# NoClassDefFoundError в android

Tags: maven, java, android, eclipse

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Использую класс Uri.Builder, и в связи с этим у меня в рантайме вываливается ошибка NoClassDefFoundError. При компляции все хорошо, ошибок нет. Насколько я понимаю, у меня отсутствует необходимый jar или что-то в этом роде. Только что начал работать с maven и пока не очень понимаю что к чему. В pom файле есть такая секция:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

В Интернете читал, что типа maven сам найдет в своих репозиториях по groupId и по artifactId, какие именно библиотеки подключать. Но все равно при запуске получаю исключение NoClassDefFoundError.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это поправить?

**Обновление**

Стек трейс очень длинный, поэтому приведу лишь часть. Если нужно, то могу потом привести и остальное:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/net/Uri$Builder
at com.dt.contentproviders.providers.Provider.createUrl(Provider.java:44)
at com.dt.contentproviders.providers.AudioProvider.get(AudioProvider.java:66)
at com.dt.contentproviders.test.ContentProviderTestTwo.testGetString(ContentProviderTestTwo.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Еще добавлю, что в проекте самого приложения появилась ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
```

Раньше этой ошибки не было. Она появилась после того, как я конвертировал проект из обычного в maven.

**Обновление 2**

Вот зависимости из pom:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>android-support-v7-appcompat</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-support-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Прежде всего, покажите стектрейс исключения.

Comment: Тогда ещё и POM покажите.

Comment: вот зависимости из pom:

    <dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
 </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>android-support-v7-appcompat</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-support-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: сделай clean проекта, и maven update

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у вас проблема в том, что вы берете из Maven либу `org.apache.httpcomponents`, непортированную под Android.

Надо написать что-то вроде:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
}
```

[Источник](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)